# Find the solutions to the $w''-z^2w=3z^2-z^4$ as Taylor series where $w(0)=0$ and $w'(0)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

We need to find the solutions of the

> $w''-z^2w=3z^2-z^4$

where

> $w(0)=0;w'(0)=1$

I wrote down the series that we can use to find the answer ($w$ as Taylor series):

$w=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nz^n$

$w'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nC_nz^{n-1}$

$w''=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)C_nz^{n-2}$

It is easy to find $C_0$ and $C_1$:

$w(0)=C_0=0$

$w'(0)=C_1=1$

I found this problem in Isaac Aramanovich **"Collection of problems on the theory of functions of a complex variable"**, problem #3.112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now insert into the equation and compare the coefficients of equal power
$$
z^n:~~~~(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}-c_{n-2}=3\delta_{n,2}-\delta_{n,4}
$$
with $c_n=0$ for $n<0$. This then allows you to compute the coefficients step-by-step.

This gives equations
$$
2c_2=0\\
6c_3=0\\
12c_4-c_0=3\\
20c_5-c_1=0\\
30c_6-c_2=-1\\
42c_7-c_3=0\\
...
$$

Comment: Okay, but what is $3δ_{n,2}−δ_{n,4}$ here? I don't know this function

Comment: That is just the usual notation for the Kronecker delta, essentially the components of a unit matrix.

Comment: It also gives the wrong answer

Comment: That you would have to explain. Up to now I get $w(z)=z+\frac14z^4+\frac1{20}z^5-\frac1{30}z^6+\frac1{224}z^8+...$

Comment: It should be $z+z^3+\frac{z^5}{4*5}+\frac{z^9}{4*5*8*9}+...$

Comment: Then $w''(z)=6z+z^3+\frac1{20}z^7+...$ so that $w''(z)-z^2w(z)=6z$ which is quite different from the given right side.

Comment: Okay, it is possible that check answers may be incorrect. I'll put a tick here